# Automatically Sizing an ASP.NET Treeview Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Is there a way to automatically resize a TreeView control so that when it is rendered (or re-rendered, if a node is expanded), the TreeView automatically resizes itself to match the overall height of the tree?

The purpose of this is to eliminate the scroll bar that accompanies the TreeView, so that the treeview blends seamlessly into the background.

Answer (score 0):

Did you explicitly set a height for the TreeView? If I remember correctly, the TreeView is always rendered as high as its content is (if no height is set).

Comment: Yes, it is explicitly set to a height.  I will try removing that.